# Using UrlData appended to root

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor

Using ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor and given the following two URLs:

```
http://example.com/sausages
http://example.com/bacon
```

Is it possible to create a content page in the root of the site which could retrieve "sausages" and "bacon" as URL data? For example:

```
Dim a As String = UrlData(0) ' This will be "sausages" or "bacon"
```

If the URL format wasn't critical then I could do this easily by creating a Razor page (e.g. page.vbhtml) to handle the request:

```
http://example.com/page/sausages
http://example.com/page/bacon
```

But the requirement is for the URLs to be in the format as first specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The in-built routing doesn't support what you want to do. The first segment of the URL must match a physical file. However, you can use the WebPageRouteHandler package (available via Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebPageRouteHandler/) to do this.

Once you have installed the package, you just need one route to be added:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapWebPageRoute("{*stem}", "~/Page.vbhtml")
```

Everything will be routed to Page.vbhtml, where the following will get you "bacon" or "sausages" or indeed anything after the domain:

```
Dim values = Context.GetRouteValue("stem")
```

You can read more about the package here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/187/More-Flexible-Routing-For-ASP.NET-Web-Pages

Comment: Fantastic package and article! I had to convert it to VB.NET but that was simple enough. Many thanks.